# Was it ever possible for Germany to win WWII?

Tags: world-war-two

Hitler's plans were very ambitious and he favored extreme expansionism.

He is said to have said (not exact):

> Some countries are spread over continents and some are mere cities

However, in his conquest of Europe (and maybe beyond?) he was sure to face opposition from Britain and other world powers which he did eventually. My question is, would it ever have been possible to win the war? Even if Britain had fallen, it would have fought on through it's colonies. America couldn't have been kept out of the war if the entire world was falling.

Could have Germany ever fought against and defeated the entire world?

Comment: "Entire world" is exaggeration in describing the Allies. Axis had their own partners, many were coerced or threatened or motivated by some other motive but same was true for many "allied nations". Also, off-topic as it is primarily opinion base. "Would have, could have, should have" sort of questions do not lead to solid answers

Comment: speculation about alternate history has no place here... But to give an opinion: if everything had gone according to the German plan, there would have been no WW2.

Comment: At the start of the war with USSR , during the first 4 months, Germany had 3 mill. captives, most of which were eager to fight against USSR regime. But Hitler insisted on their annihilation. Nazist Germany could easily win... if it were not Nazist Germany..... As the history of the 20th cent. shows, Germany could easily prevail over the Europe. Without wars. The war itself was their terrible mistake. So, they had to lose.

Comment: This question is asked repeatedly and in this formula ("the World") the answer is no. You need to substitute the word "Nazi" for "German" to start with.

Answer (score 12):

**Possible, yes. Likely, I don't think so.**

**What were the Nazis after, in the first place?**

We have to keep in mind the strategic goal of Nazi Germany: "Lebensraum", access to natural ressources not found on German soil, and a better geostrategic position on Europe's map.

As such, it is a common fallacy to say "if they only hadn't attacked the Soviet Union". Because attacking the Soviet Union was the whole *point* of Nazi Germany's grab for power. It had an abundance of arable land, and resources in the form of oil and ores. The communist movement was the greatest threat to the Nazis, politically speaking. Geostrategically, it was easier conceivable to remove the Soviet threat from one side than to defeat France *and* Britain on the other side of Germany. (Especially in the light of the outcome of the first world war.)

To point that out specifically, Germany had little to win by conquering France and Britain. The wealth of those countries was in oversea colonies, and Germany just did not have naval power to make a grab for those as well.

The Soviet Union's wealth, by comparison, seemed to be within reach.

So, what was it that the leaders of Nazi Germany envisioned as their mid-term goal?

The military goal for Operation Barbarossa was the [Arkhangelsk-Astrakhan line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-A_line), gutting the Soviet's industrial capacity and putting the new border on easily defendable natural borders like the Volga river.

It is important to understand the motivation for Germany's early moves in the war. Annexing Austria, Czechoslovakia, and Poland were directly building up to Operation Barbarossa. The invasion of Poland was answered by a declaration of war by France and Britain -- something Germany could well have done without.

The resulting invasion of Denmark and Norway was done to protect the supply of Swedish iron ore, which Germany was dependent on.

The attack on France was to remove the direct threat to Germany's western border. When France capitulated, that threat was removed. But Britain could not be convinced to withdraw from the war, not by awkward diplomacy (Ribbentrop...), not by force (Battle of Britain and the threat of Operation Sea Lion), and this is where Germany's strategy started to fall apart. Additional distractions showed up, like the North Africa campaign (initiated by Italy, and again against Britain which the Nazis had hoped to keep out of the war entirely), Crete, and Greece.

But this was all strictly a side-show. All these operations were merely for general protection of the strategic position. **The whole point of Germany's warfare was to defeat the Soviet Union.**

So, **was it ever possible for Germany to win World War II?**

I will not talk about "*likely*", just about "*possible*", and to that the answer is **YES**.

Getting Britain out of the war, as early as possible, would have been a major success. It would have freed up significant resources -- Luftwaffe units not lost in the Battle of Britain, paratrooper forces not blunted by the invasion of Crete, ground forces not tied down in Greece and North Africa. Plus, it would likely have meant keeping the USA out of the European war as well.

What would it have taken to achieve this? There is a variety of ways it *might* have happened:

- Better diplomacy. Ribbentrop was a complete dud as Ambassador to the United Kingdom. Churchill was as steadfast an enemy as Germany could get. Things might have gone better here. (Though, as commentators pointed out, Germany had little to bargain with. What little they had, together with military threats, could still have been delivered more competently.)
- Enigma not being broken. That would actually have been rather easy -- the invention of the [reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine#Reflector) by Willi Korn increased the *key space* significantly, but also *weakened* the cipher as no character could be encoded to itself. Adding another rotor or two instead would have made Enigma much more resilient to cryptanalysis.
- U-boat warfare. German submarines sank *significant* amounts of crucial supplies, to the point where Britain considered those losses non-sustainable for some time. Some more success here (e.g. through better recon / air support, focussing on subs instead of surface navy) could have been a factor into tipping the balance.
- Battle of Britain. While Operation Sea Lion was pretty much a joke when we look at it *today*, the *threat* of it was very much felt by Britain at the time. Having lost signifcant forces in France, Britain felt very ill-prepared to face an invasion (Churchill's brilliant rhetorics nonwithstanding). With a better-prepared Luftwaffe, and the focus of attacks *remaining* on airfields, radar installations etc. (instead of shifting to bombing London as they did), that threat might have been made even more immediate.

All that is not even going into what could have been done different on the Eastern Front -- troops actually being *prepared* for winter warfare, Wehrmacht actually pressing for Moscow instead of repeatedly trying to reach a decisive encirclement of Soviet forces in the open plains, things like that.

The key would have been to force Britain into an armistice. Or perhaps even persuading them into a pact with the devil *before* Poland was invaded. Again, I don't say it was *likely*, but it was *possible*, yes. Without Britain (and, by extension, the USA) as a second front, Germany *might* have reached the A-A line, and it is hard to see the Soviet Union coming back from that.

---

All that being said, *of course* we would likely be looking at subsequent wars in decades to come. The Nazi philosophy was murderous -- Hitler was very plain as early as 1925 ("Mein Kampf") that he would not stand for any neighbouring country even *capable* of threatening Germany. So eventually conflict with Britain would have been pretty much inevitable.

I shudder to think how *that* might have played out with Germany in secure possession of Soviet and Romanian oil fields and ore mines...

Comment: Ground Forces in Greece and North Africa were there only because of Mussolini's failed attempts to emulate Hitler's conquests. Britain may have made peace with Germany after fall of France but would they allow Italy to threaten their line of supply to India and other Asian colonies by dominating Mediterranean sea? I doubt that.

Comment: @NSNoob: I ignored the Mussolini question as the answer is long enough as-is. Yes, Italy was quite successful into getting Germany into sideshows they could ill afford.

Comment: Not to mention, What could Ribbentrop possibly offer to Britain to make them withdraw from the war? A peace with Nazi Germany meant giving  Europe in a plate to Germany and why should Britain allow that? Threat of German invasion could not materialize as long as Royal Navy stood strong. Kriegsmarine was in no position to decimate British naval advantage and Luftwaffe was proving ineffective in forcing the Britons to make peace. For an effective diplomacy, you have to have something to offer to other party. Germany didn't have anything to offer.

Comment: @NSNoob: The British Empire was very much about its oversea possessions, not about mainland Europe. It would have been a delicate balance between bait (continued rule of the seas and its colonies, possibly even getting them on board in anti-Bolshevism), and switch (the combined thread of U-boats, Luftwaffe, and potential invasion). Note that Sea Lion was not about *actually defeating the whole of Britain*. It was about making the *threat* of invasion being felt, to the point where Britain would fold. Britain could not really risk their navy in defending their beaches either.

Comment: @NSNoob: Aside from all that, I *had* to write up this answer if for nothing else than counterpointing that eternal "if they hadn't attacked Russia" stuff that *keeps* popping up whenever this question is raised. That's just so much beside the whole point that it's annoying.

Comment: Which is exactly the point, Without a strong fleet to destroy the royal Navy, Germany was in no position to threaten British overseas possessions or even the British mainland. So it was not a viable bargain chip. Of course if Rommel's thrust into Egypt had succeeded, Germany could use Egypt and Suez Canal as chip because they were crucial for British overseas possessions. But that didn't workout. Sea Lion wasn't a feasible undertaking and both sides knew it. Anti-Communism was a valid point but for Western Democracies, Nazism was a more immediate threat.

Comment: In any case, despite our differences on the point of Diplomacy with the Britons and Italian Question, I agree with rest of your answer and so you have my +1

Comment: How would they hold Russia? I think not possible.

Comment: @axsvl77: A river bank is a *formiddable* natural border. The A-A line pretty much *is* river banks. There have been very few large-scale amphibious assaults in modern military history, and most of those done under cover of air supremacy and full control of the waters. Assaulting a fortified and well-defended Volga bank would be military suicide.

Comment: Agreed, very formidable, but aren't there to many guerrilla fighters to control this land "forever"? (+1 btw)

Comment: @axsvl77: The idea was to enslave whatever workforce they needed (and could control) to work the fields, and quite casually starve the rest to death, or kill them outright. Once the actual combat at the front ceases, you have many hundred thousand soldiers free to do the dirty deed. There is only so much partisans can do if the occupying force is fully prepared to wipe out the native population...

Comment: The German Navy dedicating its prewar resources towards building U-Boats instead of surface raiders would have resulted in Germany having a considerably stronger submarine force in the initial stages of the war. This arguably would have taken Britain out much earlier, given how close it came to happening in spite of the relatively insignificant U-Boat strength when war was declared. An actual, meaningful presence at the war start would have been devastating.

Comment: @enderland: But without the surface forces, the invasion of Norway might have had a different result. Or the Home Fleet, without the threat of surface sorties, could have steamed off for some mischief of its own.... these what-if's are tricky.

Comment: @DevSolar how many of the big capital ships actually went to Norway? That was mostly older stuff and light ships.

Comment: @enderland: Three heavy cruisers (Hipper, Blücher, Lützow) and four light cruisers (Köln, Königsberg, Karlsruhe, Emden). Not involved were the four battleships, the Scheer, the Admiral Graf Spee, and the Prinz Eugen.

Answer (score 2):

## No, not without a major change in philosophy.

If Nazi Germany had been able to somehow defeat the Soviet Union, they certainly would have "controlled" a large portion of Eurasia for a small period of time. However, [guerrilla warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerrilla_warfare)  in the conquered territories would have made holding these territories difficult. Administering the conquered Russians would have been very resource intensive, just as it was resource intensive to administer France and other conquered territories.  The Nazis would have been stretched to thin.

What about the whole world? Could the Nazis have conquered China, India, and Africa? The answer is an emphatic no way; there is only one proven way to conquer and administer a huge empire for a long period of time. This proven method was demonstrated by the British time and time again; it involves just a little military action and a whole lot of patience, which Hitler didn't have to much of. In a sentence, the British spent 300 years double-crossing and co-opting indigenous ruling structures around the world. Why they did this, and how they did it for so many years, is another question. The fact is that the Nazi did not have the social philosophy to do this.

A grim alternative is that the Nazis would simply exterminate entire conquered populations. Perhaps they would try to liquidate the whole of Russia? I honestly don't think they would be able to do it; it would be just to much blood.

Another thought is worth considering though; maybe Germany actually won WWII? Sure, the stated goal was to control Eastern Europe and ethnic cleansing. They didn't succeed in this. But what if we re-interpret the Nazi goals? What if "Lebensraum", mentioned in the excellent post by DevSolar, was simply the end British economic hegemony over Germany? In that case, they succeeded as the British Empire collapsed within two decades of WWII. And in retrospect, Germany is doing pretty good these days economically. So maybe Germany won?

This too required a change in philosophy, and buying into the vision of the conquering Americans.

Comment: I saw a documentary once about what would happen if England was fell. The goverment had already set up such guerilla units just in case. But in the documentary said that the nazis would have taken a policy of "for every one of us you kill, we will drivd to the nearest village and kill 100 random people"

Comment: @Ovi That was their real practice in the East. The main method - burning off a whole village with all inhabitants.

Comment: @axsvl77 What blood? Fire and gas did all the work. German soldiers had only to look for not a body will get away from it. Germany brought all-Europe colonial methods into Europe itself. And Europe almost become such colony, too.

Comment: I'm speaking about the blood of the victims. I just can't believe that they could slaughter 100 million people. The Nazis may have been cruel and evil, but the scale would be just to much.

Comment: Germany could absolutely have defeated Britain and Russia in World War 2...but not Nazi Germany...not after it invaded Soviet Russia. Politics got kicked to the curb for a purely ideological struggle...against Russia and Russians? Good luck with that one...

Answer (score 1):

In a world of If, Nazi Germany couldn't win against the whole world but might have been able to negociate peace to keep what they won.

If they didn't wage war against the Soviets they would have been quite fine in Europe, only Britain to stand against them. They could have negociated a cease-fire to focus on something else, like beating totally French colonies and securing a nice chunk of North Africa. They could also have fought with the Soviets against Britain and Fascist Italy could have been usefull, Japanese could have been helped to fight against America etc etc...

So if Nazi Germany wasn't led by Hitler who was stupid enough to attack one of his closest ally and would have bothered to wait a bit to act, Nazi Germany COULD have "won" the second World-War by ending it quite soon. Then, would wage war once their power has been secured in their new lands etc etc etc.

As they did, it was utterly impossible. No one ever won while pressed on many fronts without proper backup.

Hope it helped.

Comment: And there it is again, "if they hadn't had attacked Russia"... :-(

Comment: @DevSolar Attacking Russia was not a choice. It was inevitable. Either the third reich could wait and let Stalin attack them on his time and field of choice or they could seize the initiative and strike first.

Comment: This answer comes with the sole assumption that had the Third Reich not attacked Soviet Union, Soviets would have let them be. With every German victory in the West, Stalin grew more and more nervous. It was only a matter of time before Stalin had sufficiently prepared his forces for the Push Westward.

Comment: This answer was made with the assumption that a cease fire with Britain could have been made. If you're at peace and securing your conquests, you're in a much better situation. Stalin would have waited for his power to be enough to topple Nazi Germany, but what if America thought that after all Stalin was the biggest threat?
But, since Hitler decided that striking first was the way to go...

Comment: The Nazi's defeated Soviet Russia in six weeks...but the Nazi ideology demanded and indeed got a policy of total extermination...in the end their own extermination.

Comment: @DoctorZhivago The Nazi's *thought* they had defeated the Soviets after six weeks, as the Red Army had lost basically all their front-line units. What the Nazis did not figure was the Soviet's basically limitless ability to replace those losses. The Wehrmacht kept trying to catch the Red Army in a "decisive encirclement" instead of pushing towards the Urals and breaking the infrastructural backbone. Basically, in their haste to avoid getting entangled in a war of attrition, Nazi Germany missed their one chance to do just that. Soviet Russia was dealt a severe blow, but it did not fold.

Comment: "if Nazi Germany wasn't led by Hitler" ... there wouldn't have been a Nazi party. He build it from the ground up.

Comment: @Jos the point was _if_ Hitler died in like 1940 or something, nazi germany would have still been a nazi germany, and most likely still in the war.