# If Hitler did not create a Second Front, could the war in the East have developed very differently?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler

If Hitler had decided to not attack Britain, and focused solely on Russia, and only left a big enough portion of his resources there to prevent a Second front opening up, what magnitude of resources could he have freed up to possibly make a difference in the Eastern Front?

Comment: Sorry, but this type of question focusing on 'alternate' events is off topic here  Check out the help area to see more on how to participate on the History stack.

Comment: Welcome to the History SE. Historical fiction is unfortunately off topic. I've thrown in a separate question that addresses some of your points FYI.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: I believe this question is that converse of other one; that is, if Hitler had minimized fighting against Britain (no North Africa, no submarine campaign), would he have done better against the Soviet Union?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was it ever possible for Germany to win WWII?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/32546/was-it-ever-possible-for-germany-to-win-wwii)

Comment: Tom is right, that's what I intended to get at, although the real reason of asking is as DevSolar argues if it was possible for Germany to win WW2. But, what would constitute as a win??

Comment: I tried to fix the question by exploring the factual bases of your hypothesis. "What would have happened?" is off topic here, so I changed the question to "what would have been the impact of...?" That question can be answered factually.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about alternate history (asks "what if XXX")

Comment: @Bregalad - Is it though? This "what if" scenario sounds like a pretty good description of what actually happened.

Comment: Yes, every little detail would have been different - yet with the same ending. Hitler was an incompetent loony tunes when it came to strategy, and would have found a way to sink an Axis endeavour.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I've opened a discussion on meta. https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/how-can-we-fix-counterfactual-questions/3526#3526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider one aspect of the fight against Britain; airpower. The Germans lost something like 1887 planes in the [Battle of Britain](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/battle-of-britain-75th-anniversary-the-staggering-numbers-behind-the-four-month-war-over-uks-skies-10380910.html). At the very least, most of those aircraft could have been saved by the Germans' not fighting in the Battle of Britain.

Japan's [Admiral Yamamoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0939644460) once valued the materials used to create the battleship *Yamato* as equivalent to that of 2000 bombers. By this measure, building the two (smaller) superbattleships *Bismarck* and *Tirpitz* cost the Germans something like 2500 bombers. And, of course, they were directed only against Britain.

The above numbers compare to the 2800 aircraft (the crucial arm) with which the Germans undertook [Operation Barbarossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Barbarossa). The Germans could have undertaken Barbarossa with more than twice as many planes as they actually did. Some of these extra planes (and the accompanying fuel savings) could have been used in "strategic bombing" of Soviet factories and oilfields.

So yes, minimizing the war with Britain could have made a large (favorable) difference for Germany in the East. You can decide for yourself what the impact of that extra airpower could have been.

Comment: There is also the timing to consider. Stalin had an extra year to rebuild the shit show that was the Red Army. Not only would it have been much smaller, but it would have been more disorganized and poorly equipped.

Comment: @user2259716: But don't forget that the *German* army had yet to build up as well. The force that was victorious in Poland was in *no* way capable of taking on Russia, either.

Comment: Yamamoto was nuts to make that claim, given that *Yamato* was sunk rather easily by a fraction of that number of planes

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It is a known fact that Yamamoto opposed the building of superbattleships as an unwise resource allocation, thus, although I can't find an actual source for this quote, it probably meant that he would rather have 2000 bombers than one Yamato at Midway.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I clarified the statement as follows: "Japan's Admiral Yamamoto once valued the materials used to create the battleship Yamato as equivalent to that of 2000 bombers."